# Array size in default constructor in java

Tags: java, arrays

What should I put as the size of the array in the default constructor ?

```
public Student()    
{                                                                                     
    name = " ";                                                 
    age = 0;                      
    grades = new int [?];               
    Nb_grades = 0;      
}
```

Comment: This seems totally vague, could you be a bit more clear about where you are getting stuck?

Comment: Whatever you want. Glad I could be of service.

Comment: This question seems to be opinion-based, thus I'll leave my opinion. Initialize a zero-sized array. It makes as much sense as the rest of the default attributes.

Comment: If you dont know then its better to use ArrayList.

Comment: it depends on what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's completely up to you.

You can put an initial arbitrary size, and re-size the array later if necessary (by creating a new larger array and copying the old array to the new array).

Or you can put a large enough size that should be enough for the purposes of this object.

Or you can keep it null, and initialize the array once you know what its size should be.

Or you can replace the array with an ArrayList, whose size isn't fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how many grades you want your student to have. For every grade one field in the array. But an int is maybe not a good type for grades.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use ArrayList as the grades may stand increased or decreased in number.

```
ArrayList<String> grades=new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: I did not do exactly what you want in your program, but I think you will do well arraylist, read on list, upvote, or use constant white if you want, but is more delicate.

Comment: I agreed with @Anirudh , May I know why its downvoted??

Comment: I really don't understand the downvotes..but I at least deserve to get an explanation in proper english? Unfair.

Comment: I also vote up.

Comment: I vote up, but actulize page and saw 0 and gave another look but I was saying no and was coming down to -1 then thought that another had voted -1 and so my vote is rest, I think arrylist.

Comment: Look at my profile vote cast, eh never voted in the negative one.